# Why can't I change the end date of a Quote Line. from 3/31/2025 to 5/31/2025

Tags: cpq, quotelineitem

I am not able to change the end date of a quote line in CPQ.  Why is that.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here for anyone to venture a guess. Are you getting an error? Is the field disabled? Is it perhaps tied to the Opportunity closeDate? Have you tried checking the relevant documentation to see if it's explained there?